# SQLQuery for Time In and Time Out attendance in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, sql-query-store

I have a table in oracle with the below sample output.

```
EID   | type  |   Date
24    |  IN   |03/25/2019 6:45 am
24    |  OUT  |03/25/2019 8:05 am
24    |  IN   |03/25/2019 8:06 am
24    |  IN   |03/25/2019 8:28 am
24    |  OUT  |03/25/2019 9:48 am
24    |  IN   |03/25/2019 9:52 am
24    |  IN   |03/25/2019 9:57 am
24    |  IN   |03/25/2019 10:44 am
24    |  OUT  |03/25/2019 12:16 pm
24    |  OUT  |03/25/2019 1:00 pm
24    |  IN   |03/25/2019 1:05 pm
24    |  OUT  |03/25/2019 2:21  pm
```

I want to build a query to achieve the below results:

```
EID |       TIMEIN        |    TIMEOUT            | DIIF_IN_MIN 
24  | 03/25/2019 6:45 am  | 03/25/2019 8:05 am    |   1 
24  | 03/25/2019 8:06 am  |       null            |   0
24  | 03/25/2019 8:28 am  | 03/25/2019 9:48 am    |   4
24  | 03/25/2019 9:52 am  |       null            |   0
24  | 03/25/2019 9:57 am  |       null            |   0
24  | 03/25/2019 10:44 am | 03/25/2019 12:16 pm   |   0
24  |        null         | 03/25/2019 1:00 pm    |   5
24  | 03/25/2019 1:05 pm  | 03/25/2019 2:21  pm   |   0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use such a logic by the contribution of lead window analytic function

```
with tab(eid, type, dates ) as
(
 select 24,'IN' ,timestamp'2019-03-25 06:45:00' from dual union all
 select 24,'OUT',timestamp'2019-03-25 08:05:00' from dual union all
 select 24,'IN' ,timestamp'2019-03-25 08:06:00' from dual union all
 select 24,'IN' ,timestamp'2019-03-25 08:28:00' from dual union all
 select 24,'OUT',timestamp'2019-03-25 09:48:00' from dual union all
 select 24,'IN' ,timestamp'2019-03-25 09:52:00' from dual    
)
select t1.eid, t1.dates as timein, t2.dates as timeout, 
       nvl(to_number(regexp_substr(to_char(t1.ld_dates - t2.dates),'[^:]+',1,2)),0) 
           as diff_in_minutes
  from ( select lead(dates) over (order by dates) as ld_dates, t.* 
           from tab t 
          where type = 'IN' order by dates) t1
  full join ( select * from tab where type = 'OUT' order by dates) t2
    on t1.dates <= t2.dates and ld_dates > t2.dates
 order by t1.dates;

EID TIMEIN              TIMEOUT             DIFF_IN_MINUTES
24  25.03.2019 06:45:00 25.03.2019 08:05:00 1
24  25.03.2019 08:06:00 NULL                0
24  25.03.2019 08:28:00 25.03.2019 09:48:00 4
24  25.03.2019 09:52:00 NULL                0
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://rextester.com/PEYG43102)</kbd>

Comment: still the result for last two row is not matching my request

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the following logic.

You can get all the `in`s using a `lead()` query.  Then you can get the unmatched `out`s using a `lag()`:

```
select t.eid, date as timein,
       (case when next_type = 'OUT' then next_date end) as timeout,
       ((case when next_type = 'OUT' then next_date end) - date) * (24 * 60) as diff_in_minutes
from (select t.*,
             lead(type) over (partition by eid order by date) as next_type,
             lead(type) over (partition by eid order by date) as next_date
      from t
     ) t
where type = 'IN'
union all
select t.eid, null as timein,
       date as timeout, null as diff_in_minutes
from (select t.*,
             lag(type) over (partition by eid order by date) as prev_type,
             lag(date) over (partition by eid order by date) as prev_date
      from t
     ) t
where type = 'OUT' and (prev_type <> 'IN' or prev_type is null);
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=fa712208f0f007d0af274a22c8816638) is a db<>fiddle with all your data, showing that it supports the multiple INs and OUTs.

Note this assumes that the date/time column is really a `date`.  It only converts to a `timestamp` to show the time component in the result set.

Comment: it give me an error of "inconsistent datatypes : expected char got number" in second case

Comment: @AL-MAHROUQI . . . I included a SQL Fiddle.  The code works.  You can modify your question to explain the data types of the fields you are using.  Nothing in this code is working with integers, except for the `eid` and there are no conversions.

Comment: still is not matching my result (check the last 2 row ) the time in must be null  in case if user punch two time. @Gordon Linoff

Comment: @AL-MAHROUQI . . . I don't understand.  The results are exactly the same set of rows that you have.  The last two are in a different order.  You can add an `order by` to change the ordering.

Comment: when user punch two time in 'OUT' it must come null for the first punch in timein column. Also I tried to change the order but still not showing